# Can I still use parametrical test if Shapiro-wilk test saying that my data is not normally distributed?

Tags: anova, nonparametric, parameterization

My data are mostly 0 and 1 so therefore I can't pass normality test. Can I still use parametric tests like repeated measures anova to test for significance? If the answer is yes, how can I justify that?
[[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwb6O.png)

[image]

Comment: Can you say how the numbers 0, 1, 2, and occasionally 3 arise?

Comment: @BruceET oh yeah, forgot to tell about the nature of my data. It's locomotor activirty of rats, this piece of data presented here is indicates how many times the central zone was crossed

Comment: Yes, parametric tests can be just fine, even after a normality test rejects. Normality tests can reject when there are trivial (but true) deviations from normality, particularly as the sample sizes get large (more sensitivity to tiny, inconsequential deviations), and the t-test is pretty robust. That said, you as in an unenviable situation where most of your observations are zero. You don’t need statistical tests to tell you your data aren’t normal and aren’t even close to normal. You may be more interested in extensions of the Wilcoxon Mann-Whitney U test.

Comment: Much like the t-test can be generalized to ANOVA and linear regression, the Wilcoxon test is generalized with the proportional odds logistic regression model, which is the Wilcoxon test when you use a binary indicator variable as the lone predictor (same as a t-test is linear regression on a binary indicator variable). // More important, through, what do others in your field do when they have to handle data similar to yours? You have citations in your paper; what are their statistical methods?

Comment: But these rank-based nonparametric tests may have difficulty dealing with the many ties in your data.